# using Selenium to create testing for Microsoft Dynamic 365 Business Central

Tags: selenium, dynamics-business-central

Does anyone use Selenium to do the testing in Business Central?
I am new in Selenium and I cannot pass the login screen.

I have difficulty in finding the right fields and step(s) to complete the login process

Comment: I mean how to do it in Selenium to simulate the action "Pick the existing account in the list to login"

Comment: Can you share the url or html to help you with xpath?

Comment: Where are you stuck? on the Microsoft Authenticator app step ?

Comment: I used this like to connect to the microsoft business central test environment.

Comment: Why not use the Test Framework provided by Microsoft? It provides the required tools for UI testing.